# Electron and Vue - Unknown custom element

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm starting new project using Electron and Vue.
I used the [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boilerplate to setup the project.

As soon as I try to use a component into another, I get a `Unknown custom element` error.

I've searched all around the web but nothing I've tried so far works.
Here are the two of the components I wrote:

`..../CreateAddon/AddonProgress.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>AddonProgress</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Here's where I'm trying to use it
`..../CreateAddon.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <addon-progress></addon-progress>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { AddonProgress } from './CreateAddon/AddonProgress'

export default {
  name: 'create-addon',
  components: { AddonProgress }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

The frustrating part is that the boilerplate code includes and example of a imported component, and I'm doing exactly the same thing.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the curly braces here `{ AddonProgress }`

Comment: Wow good spot, I'm wondering why this syntax is correct in TypeScript but not ES6 though...

Comment: Also weird somewhere else in the code I did ```import { ADDON_TYPES } from '../../../api/types/addon-types'``` and it works